# Javascript "err" function parameter - how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking at a Node.js code sample that uses "if (err) {//code//);" statements to control the output of its functions - but when the functions are called I don't see anything being passed to them, its as if the "err" parameter is defined by invisible code behind the scenes...

The below code is asynchronous and uses an external module from an SDK, should that be of note.

```
    /* "client.sendEvent" sends the data contained within the variable "message"
 to its destination, when this is complete the callback function "printResultFor"
 is called and a string is passed to that */

    client.sendEvent(message, printResultFor('Message'));

    //printResultFor looks like this:

    var printResultFor = function (op) {
      return function printResult(err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
            if (res) {
                console.log(op + ' status: ' + res.constructor.name);
            };

      };
    }
```

My questions are:

1. Why does this callback function need to return a nested function?

and

2. How are the values of "err" and "res" passed to this nested function?

I did wonder if the answer lies in the external module but I don't know...

(Final Note: I'm a self-taught novice with Javascript and Node, I bet this is trivial to most people but thank you for any explanations and help you can offer.)

Comment: The same way an `Event` object is provided to callbacks in `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called **Error first callback** and it's not a language feature but a convention instead.

As Fred K. Schott says in [The Node.js Way - Understanding Error-First Callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/):

> 1. The first argument of the callback is reserved for an error object. If an error occurred, it will be returned by the first err argument.
> 2. The second argument of the callback is reserved for any successful response data. If no error occurred, err will be set to null and any
>      successful data will be returned in the second argument.

Basically what it says is that if there is any error you'll know by checking the first parameter.

This is the expected behaviour for any callback based nodejs library and you should design your interfaces alike.

Comment: Great link, thanks for that! I had tried researching error handling - this explains why I never found the answer as this is more callback convention by the looks of it. Thanks again for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The `printResultFor` is called, and it returns the defined function inside.  Whatever called the `printResultFor` then calls the internal function which it now has access to, because it was returned.  It just happens in code where you aren't looking for it.

for example:

```
var printResult = printResultFor(something);

printResult(null, dataObjectHere);
```

By doing this, the `printResult` has access to the `op` variable through closure (since it was defined in the `printResultFor` function, it has access to all the variables and parameters defined in it.)

Comment: This is really helpful, I'm glad to know there are some unseen elements at play here, well unseen until I go looking for them now... Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

1. It doesn't *need* to necessarily, as there are many ways to skin many cats, but it is using a functional programming pattern known as "currying". Here is a [good introductory article](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) on the topic, related to javascript
2. It is a common pattern in node to have `err` as the first parameter in a callback. When there is no error, it is typically the value `null`. The `res` is the data you get when a error is not encountered.

Comment: I've not come across currying before, thanks for the link!